# how to handle https request response on native socket asynchronously in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous

In my C++ application, I have implemented "Reactor" design pattern using epoll. I have the Reactor class where I register all Fd (socketFd/EventFd/TimerFd) and respective handler functions. When the application starts, I run the Reactor's event loop.

In this application, I have to send https request and process the https response received. Right now I am using `CurlPP` (libcurl c++ wrapper) to send this https request. But these are synchronous and blocking call. It is hampering my performance.

Now I want to handle these https request/response asynchronously using my Reactor class. For that, I will be creating native socket and connecting to http server. Register this socketFd and respective handler function in Reactor.

To send https request on this native socket, I need some library which will take https payload as input and give me back https (SSL encrypted) http request. So that I can write this https request directly on native socket.

Same thing to handle the https response. The read/recv call on socket will return me the buffer. I need some library which will take this buffer and give me the received https payload.

I did check the APIs available in libcurl. But libcurl do not give such feature. It does have multi handle feature, but the control of socket there is with libcurl itself.

Can you please suggest any library which can provide me such feature? Also, if you have any other approach to handle these https requests asynchronously then please suggest that also.

Answer (score 2):

> To send https request on this native socket, I need some library which will take https payload as input and give me back https (SSL encrypted) http request. So that I can write this https request directly on native socket.
>
> Same thing to handle the https response. The read/recv call on socket will return me the buffer. I need some library which will take this buffer and give me the received https payload.

No. This will cause you massive pain and will never work correctly. SSL is not a block encryption protocol. It's a *stream* protocol. You will never be able to get a working implementation this way. You may get one that seems to work most of the time, but then you'll find that it breaks when, for example, a local send triggers an SSL renegotiation.

You must treat SSL as a black box that you must never, ever try to look through. Because SSL connects two bidirectional stream protocols, the black box has four (notional) ports:

1. It has an "encrypted data in" port. When you receive data from the socket, you must give it to this port.
2. It has an "encrypted data out" port. When data is sent from this port, you must send it to the socket.
3. It has a "plaintext in" port. When you want to send data to the other side, you must send it to this port.
4. It has a "plaintext out" port. When data is decrypted, it is given to you on this port.

You *must* treat these ports as independent and you *must not* assume that, for example, after you give data to the "plaintext in" port, data will come out the "encrypted data out" port. Why? Because the engine might still be waiting for a renegotiation to complete. You *must not* assume that because you gave data to the "encrypted data in" port, that means data will come out the "plaintext out" port. Why? Because it could be negotiation data or it could be part of a block.

You are thinking about the problem wrong. Go back to the drawing board, keeping in mind that you are implementing a bidirectional byte-stream protocol that is layered on top of another bidirectional byte-stream protocol.

This is knowledge earned through decades of painful experience -- ignore it at your peril.

Comment: Your points about SSL are perfectly correct, but I don't see why it contradicts to what OP has said. In short - combining manual recv/send with (Open)SSL is perfectly possible (it just requires to be a bit more careful than OP has originally specified, see your points 1-4).

Comment: It requires thinking about the problem completely different. If you start out thinking about it from a "data passes through and gets encrypted/decrypted" perspective, you will write code that will fail.

Comment: Right, but IMHO the difference between "data passes through" and "feed some data in - see  where/if you've got some data out" is not that big (and doesn't affect the rest of the program too much). What really matters that there *is* a way to convert data from an HTTP request to an encrypted-SSL (and vice versa), how to do it is a different story.

Comment: @No-BugsHare Oh, I completely disagree. If you have software that was designed with the "data passes through" model and have to fix it, it can require essentially a complete rewrite. Imagine, for example, an implementation that uses two threads, one to encrypt outbound data and one to decrypt inbound data. That will likely be unsavable.

Comment: Well, if somebody builds the whole app around this concept (and building a whole app around such a low-level concept without leaving any flexibility is a Really Bad Idea regardless of SSL or whatever else) - yes. My point, however, is that if overall design is solid, and coupling is minimized as it should be, SSL (as well as anything else on that scale) is just one small piece of puzzle, and as long as it doesn't affect other puzzle pieces - rewriting one small piece of puzzle is not a big deal (ok, it will take 2 more days - peanuts in the grand schema of things for any sizeable project).

Comment: Continued: I've had written my first comm project with OpenSSL back in 2000 or so, and have implemented it both as blocking (for Win9x clients where non-blocking sockets weren't always supported), and non-blocking (for servers and win2k+ clients). Proper design, though, allowed to encapsulate these details and overall threading structure from the rest of the program, so there was no need to rewrite more than one single implementation file (around 300 lines, which is far from being a big deal).

Answer (score 0):

Quick-and-dirty way:

One way would be to make these requests in a separate thread(s) using the same libcurl (with libcurl thread reporting reply back to main thread, where reply is processed). If performance becomes an issue, threadpool should help. That being said, such threading approach won't provide you with absolutely-best performance.